# Problem with saving chars to file

Tags: java, file, unicode, character-encoding, char

I faced in a problem with unicode characters serialization and deserialization. Here is a sample program that writes a char to file and then tries to read it. Written and read chars (*ch* and *ch2*) are different. Any suggestions why I get this behavior?

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File outfile = new File("test.txt");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outfile);
            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF-16");
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(outfile);
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-16");

            char ch = 56000;
            System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(ch));
            writer.write(ch);
            writer.close();

            char ch2 = (char) reader.read();
            System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(ch2));
            reader.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**UPD:**
Empirically found that this happens only for numbers from range 55296-57343.

Comment: What happens when you open the input stream after closing the output?

Comment: Rearranging strings of program haven't helped so this is not a reason of the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Character 56000 is [U+DAC0](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/dac0/index.htm) which is not a [valid unicode character](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Unicode/Character_reference/D000-DFFF), it's a [high surrogate character](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isHighSurrogate%28char%29). [They](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_of_Unicode_characters#Surrogates) are to be used in a pair to point characters outside the 16 bit wide [BMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Multilingual_Plane#Basic_Multilingual_Plane).